# Select en react js acumulado

Tags: reactjs, select

tengo estos requerimientos y no he podido organizarlo sin tener que cambiarlo.

1)La idea es  select is multi: deje de crecer cada vez que añado más información.Es decir, Se mantenga limitado. No he podido encontrar una opción desde este select is multi u otro componente que me permita elegir varias opciones sin que se acumule la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.